# Is there good planning GUI component (widget) for python?

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, components

I'm working on a scheduling app and looking for a calendar, timeline or other planning related GUI component for Python.

Are you aware of any ?

Comment: Do you know which gui toolkit you're using?

Comment: @Nathon : Not really, up until now I used wxpython, but if it's worth it I can consider something else.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at PyQt. It has a [calendar widget](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qcalendarwidget.html#details) and the wrapper allows you to [modify the rendering of the calendar](http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Drawing%20highlighted%20rows%20in%20a%20calendar%20widget).

Comment: Thanks, but this one is to simple.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not really clear so I can't know your needs but, maybe, you should check [faces](http://faces.homeip.net/), a powerful and free project management tool that you "program" in python.

Answer (score 0):

wxPython has two, [`CalendarCtrl`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.calendar.CalendarCtrl-class.html) and [`Calendar`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.calendar-module.html).  The former offers a more "native" feel, at least on Windows.  If you download the [wxPython Demo program](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php) you can see both in action.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I don't want something to "pick a date" but something to "display a planning".

Comment: Clarify.  Do you want to be able to specify a range of dates and times?